# update of the images in Firebase Storage

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a problem with an android app, I want to implement the ability to insert a profile photo and save it in the firebase storage, but when I want to update the image with a new one remains the previous one. The idea of ​​the update is to delete the current one and insert the new one. The phase of elimination and loading is successful, in fact in the Storage comes out the updated photo, but paradoxically the app keeps me seeing the old image. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this problem?

Comment: How do you load image from Firebase? Do you storing url of image in realtime database? If you do then possible issue is that you didn't update the url in realtime database and old one is still there.

Comment: to load the image I create a folder with the id of the user and insert the image inside so that when I download it takes the folder with the id of the user, apparently this is not the right solution. Do you advise me to adopt the URL solution?

Comment: Yeah try with approach storing url in realtime database running a new query after you upload image on Storage for example: `String downloadUrl = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();` - to get an url of uploaded image then save it in realtime database

Answer (score 0):

**if you give name of uplaoded photo in storage is unique so it will  always added second,third,fourth..but you dont give unique name...every time your image name is "profilePhoto" as string or something, and path always "userId(unique)/profilePhoto"so agail we added photo in storage to it override.and your problem solved.**